# Why is my RSA key function returning nan?

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I am currently working on a project replicating RSA key generation and testing using euclidean algorithm, extended euclidean algorithm to find the modular inverse of the value.

I used the Miller-Rabin test to choose two prime numbers, p and q.

After running the code, I am able to obtain Kpub and e, however Kpr returns as nan.

Please help!

```
#Euclidean Algorithm func

def EucAlgo(a, b):
  if a==0:
    return b
  return EucAlgo(b % a,a)

def ExEucAlgo(a,b):
  if a==0:
    return b,0,1
  gcd, s1, t1 = ExEucAlgo(b%a,a)
  #gcd of a,b
  s = t1 - (b/a) * s1
  t = s1
  return gcd, s, t

def ExEucAlgo_modInverse(a,b):
  gcd, s, t = ExEucAlgo(b,a)
  if (gcd == 1):
    i = t % a
  elif (gcd !=1):
    print("There is no inverse modulo for the input.")
  return i

def SqMul_ModularExpo(b, exp, n):
  bin_exp = bin(exp)
  base = b
  for i in range (3, len(bin_exp)):
    base = (base ** 2) % n
    if(bin_exp[i]=='1'):
      i+=1
      base = (base * b) %n 
  return base

#RSA Key generation
p=9054583561027584891319616491815785011595937977633787663340258672121877196627062461308487615739189212918799813327175451021729047602129396754172486202100997 
q=10115395220079214686776355235686624745626962891667413288473649946208213820942557513105240135405981494333016032659525466362014175268953946332375459648688023
n= p * q
phi_n= (p-1) * (q-1)
e= randint(1, phi_n - 1)
while((EucAlgo(e,phi_n)) !=1):
  e = randint(1, (phi_n-1))
d = ExEucAlgo_modInverse(e,phi_n)
print(f"\nKpr={d}")
print(f"\nKpub=(n={n})\n \ne={e}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using float point division which will result in returning float a point which when dealing with large int can result in very large floats which python can't handle so the solution is to use integer division which means `5//2=2` not `2.5`. The problem is that Now encrypting and decrypting data would result in wrong decryption. (You wont get 2 again) because of some bugs in your functions.

FIRST: use public exponent pf `65537`(prime number) which is the default for all RSA implementations(see your browser certificates) rather than finding a random one. Then after calculating the extended Euclidean algorithm which is used to find modulo inverse you dont have to make any more calculations(just return this value if GCD is 1 otherwise raise an error or whatever).

Here is the complete code that works after removing some unneeded (functions, imports, and random public exponent) **READ comments**.

```
def EucAlgo(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return b
    return EucAlgo(b % a, a)

def ExEucAlgo(a,b):
  if a==0:
    return b, 0, 1
  gcd, s1, t1 = ExEucAlgo(b%a, a)
  
  # You dont use / use // to make integer division
  s = t1 - (b//a) * s1
  t = s1
  return gcd, s, t

def ExEucAlgo_modInverse(a,b):
    gcd, s, t = ExEucAlgo(a, b)
    if (gcd == 1):
        # Just return s which is the inverse of public exponent
        return s
    elif (gcd != 1):
        # I think it's better to raise an error but it's up to you
        print("There is no inverse modulo for the input.")

#RSA Key generation
p = 9054583561027584891319616491815785011595937977633787663340258672121877196627062461308487615739189212918799813327175451021729047602129396754172486202100997
q = 10115395220079214686776355235686624745626962891667413288473649946208213820942557513105240135405981494333016032659525466362014175268953946332375459648688023
n = p * q
phi_n = (p-1) * (q-1)

# Just use fixed prime public exponent rather than trying fixed ones
e = 65537
d = ExEucAlgo_modInverse(e, phi_n)
print(f"\nKpr={d}")
print(f"\nKpub=(n={n})\n \ne={e}")

# Try to encrypt and decrypt 36
ciphertext = pow(36, e, n)
print("Encrypted data {}".format(ciphertext))
print("Decrypted data is {}".format(pow(ciphertext, d, n)))
```

Comment: Hi Khaled, I greatly appreciate this reply, however the reason I was choosing a random value for e is because I will be evaluating the exponentiation via a square and multiply algorithm, using the fixed e value doesn't seem to give me the same plaintext when checking with the square and multiply algorithm.

However you did answer my question about why nan was occurring, thank you!